# CUDA 6 unified memory performance

Tags: cuda

I have a CUDA application where I have a large array (>1000000 floats) in global memory. If I were to define this array using unified memory syntax, would CUDA also figure out ways of making my program run faster by spreading the array across shared memory? Does the unified memory architecture ever know to use shared memory instead of global memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UM does not have  anything to do with shared memory. Shared memory must still be explicitly allocated and managed separately.

You may wish to review the UM section at the end of the [programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-unified-memory-programming-hd)